# Index Match with several results

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I want to show several results with an Index Match formula,

I have this board in A1

[image]

And I want to show every number relatives to "Paris in A3 like 1,2,4, 7.

I tried :

```
={INDEX($A$1:$A$7,MATCH("Paris",$A$A:$B$B;0))}
={INDEX($A$1:$A$7,MATCH("Paris",$A$A:$B$B;0)0)}
={INDEX($A$1:$A$7,MATCH("Paris",$A$A:$B$B);0)}
```

But it doesn't works and I Don't know why...

Comment: What do you mean by *doesn't work*? The specifics should always be part of your question.  In your case, both the syntax and the logic seem faulty.  But in other cases it may not be so obvious.

Comment: As already explained by Ron. MATCH will always return the first instance. However, I wanted to give you a few tips regarding your original attempts. You cannot use `$A$A:$A$7`as a reference, this won't be recognized by Excel. Instead, you need to change it to `$A$1:$A$7`. The same goes for `MATCH` part - `$A$A:$B$B` is not a valid reference; change it to `$B$1:$B$7`. You are also mixing `,` and `;` as formula separators - be mindful of that.

Comment: yes, thank you for the tip, it comes from because I translate my formula in English… But all this kind of mistakes is not done in my French formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MATCH` will always match the **first** instance.  You need to generate an array of all the instances that match `Paris`, and then use that value in the `INDEX` function.

Also, in your posted formulas, you are using both the comma and semicolon as separators. That will also cause your formula to fail.  Use only the proper separator for your system settings.

So something like: *where **C1** contains the city of choice*

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$7,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/($B$1:$B$7=$C$1)*ROW($A$1:$A$7),ROWS($1:1))),"")
```

and fill down as far as you need.

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! It works well, I translated it in French with =SIERREUR(INDEX($A$1:$A$7;AGREGAT(15;6;1/($B$1:$B$7=$C$1)*LIGNE($A$1:$A$7);LIGNES($1:1)));"").

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, if you have access to `TEXTJOIN` formula, you can use the following Array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>):

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,IF($B$1:$B$7="Paris",$A$1:$A$7,""))
```

[image]